# In Elastic Beanstalk, how to set existing security group to load balancer with .ebextensions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm trying to set existing Security Group for the ELB in my Elastic Beanstalk application with `.ebextensions`.

For some reason, .configs like

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:loadbalancer:
    SecurityGroups: sg-abcd1234
```

Don't seem to do anything. Also, since that existing SG is strictly defined, I don't want to use `ManagedSecurityGroup` since that would modify the existing SG.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The question is the namespace of Application Load Balancer `aws:elbv2` (different from Elastic Load Balancer classic `aws:elb`)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-applicationloadbalancer.html

this works in ALB

```
option_settings:
  - namespace:  aws:elbv2:loadbalancer
    option_name:  ManagedSecurityGroup
    value:  sg-XXXXXXXX
  - namespace:  aws:elbv2:loadbalancer
    option_name:  SecurityGroups
    value:  sg-XXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your own security groups for your ELB with SecurityGroups option setting and beanstalk will associate your ELB with that security group. In addition beanstalk will create a new security group which allows ingress and egress on HTTP port 80 on that new security group. Beanstalk will not modify the security group you specified in the option setting above.

When you say it doesn't seem to be doing anything, do you mean it is not attached to the ELB? It should get attached to the ELB in addition to a new security groups. Can you confirm by checking the security groups associated with your ELB in the ELB console.

If you do not want beanstalk to create a new security group, then you can specify that security group managed security group option setting as well but that would update your security group and also provide ingress from that security group to your EC2 security groups.

If you don't want your security group to be modified then using the option setting is the way to go. It will create a new security group and attach both the new security group and your security group to the ELB. If you can explain what specific issues you are having with this setup, then I can explain more.

Comment: Like I said, what I need is a way to automatically set the security group on environment build-time, not with manual fondling of the console, so that is not a solution. Also, SG on EB deploy applies only on servers, not ELB itself. I am also aware that if I manually set the SG, it doesn't get modified, that is why I mentioned `ManagedSecurityGroup`, which (according the docs) will be modified if you provide it with `.ebextensions`.

Comment: So if you provide your own security group and do not want it to be modified then currently beanstalk will always create a new security group in addition to your security group and associate it with the ELB. These are essentially the two options as of today.